Cryptomatte is black in animation rendering with File Output node
I use Blender 4.2 LTS.
When I render only one image by clicking "Render > Render Image" and output my cryptomatte's matte - output to the viewer node it looks fine. It is not completely white, but saved as an EXR it becomes perfect white, saved as a PNG the matte is still not perfectly white.
When I render an animation by "Render > Render Animation" and connect the Cryptomatte's matte - output to the file output, set to EXR, it turns out black. When I set the file output to PNG the result is a perfect white mask.
This is my blend file:

Is this a bug? It seems like it.
This is my node setup:


What is the issue shown by the "!" triangle on the Render Layers node ? Also, note that EXR doesn't take into account your color managment settings, whereas PNG writes the image with the color managment. So, the issue of light gray VS white is expected. Not sure why you'd get a black image on the File Output though. You'll increase your chance if you share you file : https://blend-exchange.com/.

I added a blend file if someone wants to take a look at it

Tried it with the file. I cannot reproduce the issue no matter what I do. It just works fine for me with EXR and Blender 4.2.1 on Windows 11 with CPU as well as GPU compositing also with CPU as well as GPU rendering. Must be a bug, maybe in GPU drivers?.. I mean I am ignoring the color management issue with PNGs since the white coming out as light grey is just because it goes through color transform set in color management settings. Anything unusual about your setup, OS, hardware?

Are you viewing the EXR files in Blender? Might it be a problem with viewing EXR files?

Same with 4.2.3 LTS - everything works fine for me. I would try updating GPU drivers, Make sure Blender is installed correctly, that you have official release, not a daily build. If nothing helps, you should report the bug.

Bug still occurs, I updated Blender to 4.2.3 LTS, installed the newest studio driver for NVIDIA and only look at EXRs in Photoshop.
I will create a bug report on the Blender website

"and only look at EXRs in Photoshop" Could you check them in Blender?

When I looked at the crypto mattes in Photoshop they appear black, because Photoshop does not have native EXR support. Inside of Blender they appeared correctly.
Installing the free OpenEXR plugin for Photoshop fixed it.
https://www.exr-io.com/
